# How do I switch Ghidra to showing canonical register names instead of aliases?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, disassembly, ghidra

I am new to [Ghidra SRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghidra).

How do I switch Ghidra's view mode to display canonical (real world) register names instead of such aliases as `param_1` and `param_2` ?

Here is a screenshot of a CodeBrowser showing a listing of ASM commands which I talk about. Aliases `param_1` and `param_2` have purple / violet colour.
[image]

SRE's version is 10.2.3 if that matters.

I have searched all the settings, but I did not find it.

By the way, the `Always Show Primary Reference` switch is enabled in `Edit -> Tool Options -> Listing Fields -> Operands Field -> Always Show Primary Reference`. So, I do not know why it keeps showing aliases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I have found a solution.

I need to disable following switches as well:

- `Markup Inferred Variable References`
- `Markup Register Variable References`

Then the CodeBrowsers begins showing `ECX` instead of `param_1` and `EDX` instead of `param_2`.
I found this solution here: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ghidra/comments/tns5n9/is_it_possible_to_toggle_or_turn_off_relabing_rcx/)

**Updated settings**
(`Edit -> Tool Options -> Listing Fields -> Operands Field`):
[image: Updated Settings]

**Result**
(Canonical Register Names are used instead of aliases):
[image: Canonical Register Names]

I hope, this will save someone's time as well.